# QT project not compiling - Variable QMAKE_CXX.COMPILER_MACROS is not defined mac

Tags: macos, qt

Totally new to QT.

Hi all I have installed QT on my MAC(Sierra - 10.12.2). I have a requirement of which I am not sure is feasible but I have to work on a project in which I have to add a module to an application which is built for Linux(Desktop Application).
I have QT Creator 4.3.0 which is based on QT 5.8.0 (Clang 7.0). 
I am opening the project and It gives me an error

> ../Softwares/XCode: No such file or directory

but I have Xcode in that same directory.
and another error which I got was

> > Variable QMAKE_CXX.COMPILER_MACROS is not defined mac

I'am not sure if I am going in the write direction? 
Is it possible to create an application for linux desktop on Mac?

And If yes then how to resolve these errors ?

Thank you all !!!